# Sort multidimensional array by choosing the last 10 records

Tags: javascript

I need to sort this array by number, then I need to choose the last 10 records from highest to lowest.

```js
    function compressArray(original) {

      var compressed = [];
      // make a copy of the input array
      var copy = original.slice(0);

      // first loop goes over every element
      for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {

        var myCount = 0;  
        // loop over every element in the copy and see if it's the same
        for (var w = 0; w < copy.length; w++) {
          if (original[i] == copy[w]) {
            // increase amount of times duplicate is found
            myCount++;
            // sets item to undefined
            delete copy[w];
          }
        }

        if (myCount > 1) {
          var a = new Object();
          a.value = original[i];
          a.count = myCount;
          compressed.push(a);
        }
      }

      return compressed;
    };
```

Result:

```js
 [{ name: 'Peter', number: 166 },
  { name: 'Frank', number: 165 },
  { name: 'Ana', number: 149 },
  { name: 'Robert', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Jordi', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Alan', number: 168 },
  { name: 'Carlos', number: 174 },
  { name: 'Carena', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Bruce', number: 167 },
  { name: 'Edison', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Paloma', number: 145 },
  { name: 'Devoto', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Julia', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Reina', number: 153 },
  { name: 'Karen', number: 163 },
  { name: 'Violet', number: 170 },]
```

I need this result with the last 10 records..

[ 'Carlos',
      'Violet',
      'Alan',
      'Bruce',
      '......',
      '......',
      '......',
      '......',
      '......',
      '......',]

Comment: so slice off the last 10 records

Comment: Sort by value of `number` and slice the required 10 records.

Comment: what does the original array look like?

Answer (score 1):

`.sort`, `.slice(-10)`, `.reverse()` and `.map()`

```js
var array = [{ name: 'Peter', number: 166 },  { name: 'Frank', number: 165 },  { name: 'Ana', number: 149 },  { name: 'Robert', number: 150 },  { name: 'Jordi', number: 162 },  { name: 'Alan', number: 168 },  { name: 'Carlos', number: 174 },  { name: 'Carena', number: 159 },  { name: 'Bruce', number: 167 },  { name: 'Edison', number: 159 },  { name: 'Paloma', number: 145 },  { name: 'Devoto', number: 162 },  { name: 'Julia', number: 150 },  { name: 'Reina', number: 153 },  { name: 'Karen', number: 163 },  { name: 'Violet', number: 170 }];

var result = array.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
                  .slice(-10)
                  .reverse()
                  .map(n => n.name)

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly make your code wrap so that its more readable,

Comment: Just use `array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
                  .slice(0, 10)`. No `.reverse()` necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To sort the array by decreasing number, do this:

```
array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
```

You can then get the 10 largest elements in decreasing order by slicing the first 10 elements:

```
array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
     .slice(0, 10)
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let array =
 [{ name: 'Peter', number: 166 },
  { name: 'Frank', number: 165 },
  { name: 'Ana', number: 149 },
  { name: 'Robert', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Jordi', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Alan', number: 168 },
  { name: 'Carlos', number: 174 },
  { name: 'Carena', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Bruce', number: 167 },
  { name: 'Edison', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Paloma', number: 145 },
  { name: 'Devoto', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Julia', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Reina', number: 153 },
  { name: 'Karen', number: 163 },
  { name: 'Violet', number: 170 }];
  
let sort = array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number).slice(0, 10);
 
console.log(sort);
```

If you want *only* the names in the output, map the elements to their names:

```
array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
     .slice(0, 10)
     .map(e => e.name);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
let array =
 [{ name: 'Peter', number: 166 },
  { name: 'Frank', number: 165 },
  { name: 'Ana', number: 149 },
  { name: 'Robert', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Jordi', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Alan', number: 168 },
  { name: 'Carlos', number: 174 },
  { name: 'Carena', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Bruce', number: 167 },
  { name: 'Edison', number: 159 },
  { name: 'Paloma', number: 145 },
  { name: 'Devoto', number: 162 },
  { name: 'Julia', number: 150 },
  { name: 'Reina', number: 153 },
  { name: 'Karen', number: 163 },
  { name: 'Violet', number: 170 }];
  
let sort = array.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
                .slice(0, 10)
                .map(e => e.name);
 
console.log(sort);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const result = original.sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number).slice(-10).reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution:

```
//if duplicates are OK
function compressArray(array) {
    return array
             .sort((a,b) => b.number - a.number )
             .map(result => result.name);
             .slice(0,10)
}
```

Or, if duplicates are NOT OK. Remove them first

Comment: Are you sure `.name`?

Comment: should be number

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with .sort and .slice

try:

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number);
let new_arr = arr.slice(0, 10);
```

Comment: This will slice the first 9 elements.  Should be `arr.slice(0, 10)`.